# Insert line after specific line

Tags: c#

How can I insert a line after specific line?

```
[something]
asdasd
asdasd

[test]
dw
dw
```

Something like `void insertAfter(string line)`.

I know how to read lines after specific, but when I tried to do with writing, it doesn't work.

Comment: you want to do this for collection?can you share you code?

Comment: Are you talking about a text file? A list or other type of collection of strings (aka "lines")?

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    public bool TryInsertAfter(List<string> fileLines, String searchAfterText, String insertAfterText)
    {
        var index = fileLines.IndexOf(searchAfterText);
        if( index > -1 )
        {
           fileLines.Insert(++index, insertAfterText);
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

*maybe the insert with index is off-by-on, so test it*

Comment: should it not be `index + searchAfterText.Length`  instead of ++index?

Comment: no, the index is actually the line number (zero indexed). So when it finds an index/line number - it inserts on the line after.

Comment: my mistake. did not consider that the filelines was already split..